# PowerShell script to log in to Linkedin

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, ui-automation

Fairly new to PowerShell and exploring its capabilities.  I have created the following script to automatically log in to LinkedIn, but it opens the web page and does nothing else, can some please assist?  I wish to use the script to log in to a web status page and search for issues for alerting purposes, thank you.

**PowerShell Script**

```
$username = "Username" 
$password = "Password" 
$ie = New-Object -com InternetExplorer.Application 
$ie.visible=$true
$ie.navigate("https://www.linkedin.com") 
while($ie.ReadyState -ne 4) {start-sleep -m 100} 
$usernameElement = $ie.document.getElementById("login-email").value= "$username" 
$ie.document.getElementById("login-password").value = "$password" 
$ie.document.getElementById("login-submit").submit()
start-sleep 20
```

Comment: Try replacing the `start-sleep 100` with `echo Ok`. Now if it keeps echoing ok, you know your have the wrong ready state code (4). Idk for sure, but I thought it was 200...

Comment: Hi Levi, thanks for the prompt response here; I tried the "echo ok" and the script displayed "All OK's".  I am also running the script as "Administrator"; the web page opens and you can see the Username / Password being entered, but doesn't actually login to the web site.  Any ideas as to why the web page will not login?

Answer (score 0):

OK, took me a while, but I figured out the issue. On LinkedIn specifically, the `login-submit` button has two notable properties: `isDisabled` and `disabled`. Those need to be both changed to `$true` before it can be clicked. Also, change the function called on it from `.submit()` to `.click()`. Also, a quick tip: After the script is done (I'm not sure if this is still true, because you seem to manually close it afterwards), `$ie` is kept under your script's management. To release it, call this command (after you manually close it, so it might be hard to get in there):

```
[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie) #>
```

Not really sure why, I just know it keeps it out of the way and is apparently equivalent to killing it from the task manager.